# .htaccess change displayed url

Tags: .htaccess

is there any way to get example.com/all-requests to go to example.com/forum/all-requests but still have the browser url show the former? (iow not just a simple forward call).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omitting the `[R]` flag while still keeping the redirect local will do an internal redirect, which only modifies httpd's parameters as to what to call/display.